# Vue CLI 3 - Is there a way to see HTMLWebpackPlugin's templateParameters function contents?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

When I run `vue inspect` it says that the templateParameters function was `omitted long function`.

```
templateParameters: function () { /* omitted long function */ },
```

I'm interested in seeing what's in here. Is there a way to view the long function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just discovered under the options for the `vue inspect` command you can use the `-v` verbose option to see the full function definitions.

```
vue inspect --help

  Usage: inspect [options] [paths...]

  inspect the webpack config in a project with vue-cli-service

  Options:

    --mode <mode>
    --rule <ruleName>      inspect a specific module rule
    --plugin <pluginName>  inspect a specific plugin
    --rules                list all module rule names
    --plugins              list all plugin names
    -v --verbose           Show full function definitions in output
    -h, --help             output usage information
```